# database restore with filestream on Windows Server 2016 renames data file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, filestream, windows-server

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 sp2 that has filestream enabled. Restore of the database on a Win10 machine works as it should.

However, on Windows Server 2016, the data directory (file) for the filestream gets renamed. So the restore on Win10 leaves a `CSFiles01` data directory for the same named database. The Windows Server 2016 restore creates the data directory `CSFiles01.CSFiles01`.

I have no idea why the renaming occurs. Subsequent restore start a `CSFiles01_2.csfiles01` pattern. After days of working with this, I'm guessing that Windows Server 2016 is the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you restoring to a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance? SQL 2008 R2 is not supported on Win10 or Windows Server 2016.

Comment: True, not supported but as discussed elsewhere in these forums, still usable. All aspects of a SQL app work, just can't restore 1 database that's a filestream enabled database. Converting to 2014 SQL Server is likely the next step, although it'll be a shot-in-the-dark since I can't explain a behavior that has exhibited itself only on one 2016 Windows Server installation.

Comment: Is renaming causing any issues for you or you are just curious to know ?

Comment: This is an issue. It causes a failure in an SQL Server app. The expectation is that image data is found in csfiles01, not csfiles01.csfiles01.